# Why "C:\Program Files" used as default. Is there any violations or degradation in performance if we change it?

Tags: installation

Why does Microsoft recommend "C:\Program Files" for default installation destination? Are there any specific reason for that? And if I change the location is that going to effect the performance of the system and the application?

Answer (score 12):

Since it is the default, lots of things in Windows just assume that's what it is.

It's not a performance issue, but a user changing it might break things unexpectedly.  It might be a good thing to test for.

You should definitely refer to the %ProgramFiles% environment variable in your program rather than a hard-coded path.

Comment: Especially since the name of that directory depends on the language version of Windows. In German Windows versions it's called "Programme". Whenever I see something installing itself to "Program Files" I know that it hardcoded that value instead of looking it up. Most applications do it right.

Comment: And in Vista x64 some apps get installed to "Program Files (x86)" when they are 32bit apps. Never hard code the installation path! Use system defaults, that's what they're there for.

Comment: On Vista 64, 32-bit apps should be installed to the (x86) folder

Answer (score 4):

It makes computer management easier.

- Support staff knows exactly where applications are located.
- By separating the rarely changing applications ("C:\program Files") from the rapidly change user data ("C:\Documents and Settings") more efficient backup strategies can be implemented.
- It allows the C:\Program Files directory tree to be set as "Everyone readable; Admin-writable", to prevent virus installs and accidental deletion.

Answer (score 2):

It's a convention that ensures proper interoperation between your program and the OS's application and security models.  If you're writing typical application software, I would strongly recommend against going against the convention here.  As an admin, an app that tried to install somewhere else should send up red flags all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular reason you NEED to install in any particular folder (barring a few exceptions where you can't).

However, think hard about why you're asking this. If you want to hardcode your path, that is laziness and you can get burned on it. Make sure your program can handle being installed in the folder of your user's choice. What if you hardcode in C:\BuggyProgram\ and your user wants to install you in his J: drive? You're FUBAR'ed then.

In short, a well written program doesn't really CARE where it is installed. Take that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that in Vista they've also added a little more security on the Program Files folder itself so that rogue programs can't mess up other programs in the same general directory area. If you're trying to follow the Microsoft conventions, they now ask that you put all "Common" application data in the C:\ProgramData folder, which gives the application and a little more control over it.

In addition, you can also use the [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx)s to define your program data and program files folders so that they'll be properly referenced regardless if it is XP or Vista (where some folders have changed).

Answer (score 1):

"C:\Program Files" is just a convention, although it certainly is handy to have a single directory where all program files reside.  The directory can also be hidden from clumsy casual users who might otherwise unintentionally delete program files.  However, with that said, you can install an application anywhere you can write to.

Comment: "you can install an application anywhere you can write to." You mean anywhere that the account running the install can write to.

Comment: Right, or if you're on Vista, anywhere that a user who approves the UAC prompt can write to.

Answer (score 1):

That's the location that most users, and admins, expect to find their applications installed in.  It's really more of a convention than anything else.  I would suggest that it's a reasonable default, but you could allow the user the ability to change the location during the installation if they desire.  In any event you should write your application to work without a dependence on a fixed installation directory if at all possible (and generally it is).  You shouldn't see any performance differences from another install location unless it happens to be on a slower or more heavily accessed drive.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that often in Enterprises, security is setup on the machine so that a typical user can only install to the C:\Program Files directory.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files" is actually only the default in *English* versions of Windows. In the German version, it's called "C:\Programme", so never rely on the fact that this folder exists or what its name is. Always use `%ProgramFiles%`.

I also assume that the name was introduced to make more programs handle spaces (and other weird characters in paths) correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible in Windows..

1. Open `Regedit`
2. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
3. On the right window, double click on the key `ProgramFilesDir` and modify it to include the new path.